# Android - Select number syncced from facebook but returns null

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

So, I'm reading in phone numbers from the built-in contact list and the selected phone number should be put into a text box. This works all fine and dandy for phone numbers that come from google or have been put in manually by the user. However, when it comes to selecting a number that was synced from Facebook to the user's phone, the cursor returns NULL and the text box remains empty.

Here is the code that I'm using to select the number:

```
    if (data != null) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();

        if (uri != null) {
            Cursor c = null;
            try {
                c = getContentResolver()
                        .query(uri,
                                new String[] {
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, },
                                null, null, null);

                if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                    String number = c.getString(0);
                    txtPhoneNo.setText(number);
                }
            } finally {
                if (c != null) {
                    c.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So, is there anything I can do that will allow me to get the Facebook synced phone numbers, or am I stuck with not being able to use those numbers?